# Does there exist a spherical quadrilateral with all angles pi/2?

Tags: geometry, spherical-geometry

Does there exist a spherical quadrilateral with all angles pi/2?

I do not think so but I am not sure. I am unable to really visualize this.

Please offer suggestions.
Thank you.

Comment: I think you will find: as the size of a quadrilateral shrinks to zero, the sum of the angles approaches $2\pi$.  But that limiting value is not achieved.

Comment: You're right. Such a quadrilateral cannot exist. That's because we have (if $a,b,c,d$ are the angles of the quadrilaterial, and $A$ is its area, and $R$ is the sphere's radius): $a+b+c+d=2\pi+A/R^2$.

Comment: As a side note, if you allow some of the angles to be *exterior* rather than *interior*, then on the unit sphere, the quad whose vertices, in order, are $A = (0, 1, 0)$, $B = (1, 0, 0)$, $C = (-1, 0, 0)$ and $D = (0, -1, 0)$, with the arc between $B$ and $C$ containing the point $(0, 0, 1)$ and the arc between $D$ and $A$ containing $(0, 0, -1)$, has four angles that are $\pi/2$.

Answer (score -1):

Wouldn't having all the angles pi/2 just make the figure a regular square because every angle would be 90 degrees?

Comment: No. Rules such as "the interior angles of a polygon add up to 360 degrees" from the plane don't apply when you move to a sphere. For example, on the surface of a sphere, you can have a triangle where all three angles are 90 degrees: take the vertices to be the north pole and two points a quarter of the way around the equator from each other.